# Custom var_dump function in PHP

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I am making a custom debugging helper function similar to Laravel's dd function. I have a `helpers.php` file where the function is declared and that file is included into my project. Here's the code of the function, though it doesn't really matter:

```
/**
 * Simply dumps all arguments and then dies, like Laravel's dd function
 */
function dd() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        var_dump($arg);
    }
    die();
}
```

Everything's working good, with one tiny inconvenience. When I am calling the function from the file I want to debug, I am getting a line like this: `/path/to/project/root/helpers.php:49:` which obviously as expected indicates the line where var_dump is called inside my `helpers.php` file. Now, ideally, I would instead like to see the code reference where I am calling the `dd` function. I know it's a really tiny matter, but I am wondering if there is a way.

**UPDATE**

Side note for future readers, luckily xdebug has an option to omit the reference code from the var_dump. To do this, set the php.ini option `xdebug.overload_var_dump` to 1 (for me it was 2 by default). Personally I do this in runtime, since I want the effect during my custom dumping `ini_set("xdebug.overload_var_dump", "1");`

So, after turning off the code reference from xdebug, you can add your own reference from `debug_backtrace()` as @JustOnUnderMillions suggested like this:

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();
echo '<small>';
highlight_string($trace[0]['file'] . ':' . $trace[0]['line'] . ':' . PHP_EOL);
echo '</small>';
```

Comment: This function can help you out http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Nice, I was completely unaware of that function, looks like the way to go for low-level debugging. Thanks !

Comment: My question might be a bit stupid (as I do not know the full context -- how do you actually plan to use it etc) .. but why not use actual xdebug and your editor/IDE (e.g. NetBeans/PhpStorm/whatever-else-that-supports-xdebug)? It's interactive: you can see other values as well; you can alter existing values to see how your code will behave in such situation without re-running the code etc. If xdebug is not an option or cannot be used (e.g. shared hosting etc) why not try PHP 5.6 built-in debugger http://phpdbg.com/ (if it's available, of course)

Comment: @LazyOne Well, truth is I've been using PhpStorm for about two months now and I never used an IDE for web development before, so that must be one of the thousand features that I am not aware of. About xdebug I am still using it, I just omit the first line where the triggering line of code is mentioned and show the actual line where the dumping is called instead. `xdebug.overload_var_dump` must be 0 in order to completely switch it off, I have set it to mode 1 instead of default mode 2